# Insert new line in struts2 messages.properties

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2, resourcebundle

I want to display the error message in two lines in Struts2

```
User Name is not valid
Password is not valid
```

and my property is:

```
username.password.errrorMsg: User Name is not valid \n Password is not valid.
```

I added `\n` but its displaying in single line.

Can you suggest to display in two lines?

Comment: Don't do that. Use separate messages.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr, i have used separated messages, May i know the reason why we need to use separate message ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a message format then `\n` symbol add a new line character. If you want to display this message with `actionerror` or `actionmessage` tags you need to use `<br>` and let it not escape. For example

```
<s:actionmessage escape="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, i just put <br> in properties file and used <s:actionmessage escape="false"/> in jsp, it worked thanks a lot –

Answer (score 2):

Because new line/breaking character depends on where do you use/show message it is better to use different messages for that.

```
invalid.userName = User Name is not valid
invalid.password = Password is not valid
```

In this way you can use them separately in case you want to show specific message and display them as you want.

---

If you displaying them in HTML/JSP using S2 `<s:text>` tag then `<br/>` should work. But several tags are escaping HTML so for example to use this kind of message in `<s:property>` with `getText()` you need to set `escapeHTML` attribute to false.

Comment: ok, but i am adding action error like

         addActionError(getText("username.password.errrorMsg"))

Comment: @sree: As I said there are several S2 tags that escapes HTML, `<s:actionerror>` is one of them. You can use `escape` attribute to control whether is escapes message or not.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr , i just put <br> in properties file and used <s:actionmessage escape="false"/> in jsp, it worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Probably < br/> (without the space between < and b :P), as the output format is html.

Comment: username.password.errrorMsg: User Name is not valid <br> Password is not valid.

And it displaying : User Name is not valid <br> Password is not valid.

Comment: i am adding action error like addActionError(getText("username.password.errrorMsg"))

Comment: Do you use <html:errors/> in your jsp or another tag to display the error messages returned by the action?